# Hibernate not creating ElementCollection table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Hibernate is not generating a table for the dataAttributes Map in the MetaData class below. The code compiles but table not found at runtime.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



@Entity
public class Metadata{


    private Integer id;

    private Map<String,String> dataAttributes;

    public Metadata(){
        dataAttributes = new HashMap<>();

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addDataAttribute(String key, String value){
        dataAttributes.put(key,value);
    }

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name="key")
    @Column(name="value")
    @CollectionTable(name="data_attributes", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="metaData_id"))
    public Map<String, String> getDataAttributes() {
        return dataAttributes;
    }

    public void setDataAttributes(Map<String, String> dataAttributes) {
        this.dataAttributes = dataAttributes;
    }


}
```

All the other entities and tables are created as expected but this one is never generated and I get "Table 'nppcvis.data_attributes' doesn't exist"  when trying to save an entity that has a one-to-one relationship with MetaData with cascade=all

I'm using the following property :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Removing all annotations aside from @ElementCollection result in table being created. Obviously no control over naming but it works.

Comment: Amazing. This whole time I was missing `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to get my join tables and sequence generators automatically created by Hibernate. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing all annotations aside from @ElementCollection result in table being created. Obviously no control over naming but it works.

Comment: I had to remove @MapKeyColumn only. That sucks because I cannot specify length of keys....

Comment: I had to add @CollectionTable. Hibernate is sometimes voodoo to me.

Comment: The root cause for this problem is most likely [the answer by Oziaka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970624/hibernate-not-creating-elementcollection-table/62847254#62847254): The usage of SQL keywords such as "value" and "key" as column identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Not allowed to assign name in @MapKeyColumn as key but you can wrap in \" like here
"\"key\""
In your case:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="\"key\"")
@Column(name="value")
@CollectionTable(name="data_attributes", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="metaData_id"))
public Map<String, String> getDataAttributes() {
    return dataAttributes;
}
```

Comment: Additional information: At least since H2 2.x (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15092), a lot of SQL keywords like "key" and "value" (see http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords for more) can no longer be used as identifiers without quoting.  - Hibernate provides ways around this (e.g., https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_quoting_options), but the safe way is probably to not use keywords as identifier names.